# Restricting user from chosing a value in picklist

Tags: salesforce, validationrules

I am having a requirement in  the sales force where the user has to chose values from picklist.But the twist is the user has to select first received and then only it has to allow user to select recived.Can anyone tell me how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> Go to Setup | Customize for Standard Objects or Create for Custom
>
> Objects | Click on Record types Then select the record type that you
>
> need to change You'll see a section Picklists Available for Editing
>
> You can specify which values should appear for the record type

Comment: record type is not an option as we dont have reocord type.Thing is the record has to pass serious of actions instead if a user select a the last action we should not allow the user from saving it.